# PL/SQL bulk collect into associative array with sparse key

Tags: oracle, plsql, associative-array

I want to execute a SQL query inside PL/SQL and populate the results into an associative array, where one of the columns in the SQL becomes the key in the associative array. For example, say I have a table `Person` with columns

```
PERSON_ID   INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY
PERSON_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
```

...and values like:

```
 PERSON_ID  |  PERSON_NAME
 ------------------------
 6          |  Alice
 15         |  Bob
 1234       |  Carol
```

I want to bulk collect this table into a `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY INTEGER` such that the key `6` in this associative array has the value `Alice` and so on. Can this be done in PL/SQL? If so, how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you have to use either 2 collections (id, name) or one whose element type is a record.

Here's a sample of the latter:

```
  cursor getPersonsCursor is
    SELECT ID, Name
    FROM   Persons
    WHERE  ...;

  subtype TPerson is getPersonsCursor%rowtype;
  type TPersonList is table of TPerson;
  persons TPersonList;
begin

open getPersonsCursor;
fetch getPersonsCursor
  bulk collect into persons;
close getPersonsCursor;

if persons.Count > 0 then
  for i in persons.First .. persons.Last loop
    yourAssocArray(persons(i).ID) := persons(i).Name;
  end loop;
end if;
```

Comment: +1. If the number of rows is (or ever will be) very large, consider using a LIMIT clause to prevent excessive PGA memory consumption.

Comment: yeah, I do that as well to allow better scaling. Thought it would be a bit over-the-top, though.

Answer (score 9):

If we want to specify the value in an associative array's index then we have to use this syntax:

```
SQL> declare
  2      type n_array is table of varchar2(30)
  3           index by binary_integer;
  4      emp_names n_array;
  5  begin
  6      for r in ( select ename, empno from emp )
  7      loop
  8          emp_names(r.empno) := r.ename;
  9      end loop;
 10
 11      dbms_output.put_line('count='||emp_names.count()
 12                               ||'::last='||emp_names.last());
 13      dbms_output.put_line(emp_names(8085));
 14
 15  end;
 16  /
count=19::last=8085
TRICHLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

We *can* populate associative arrays with bulk collect but only if the index is an integer, and we are happy to index by (an implicit) ROWNUM, i.e not a sparse key...

```
SQL> declare
  2      type n_array is table of varchar2(30)
  3           index by binary_integer;
  4      emp_names n_array;
  5  begin
  6      select ename
  7      bulk collect into emp_names
  8      from emp ;
  9
 10      dbms_output.put_line('count='||emp_names.count()
 11                               ||'::last='||emp_names.last());
 12      dbms_output.put_line(emp_names(19));
 13
 14  end;
 15  /
count=19::last=19
FEUERSTEIN

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

To be fair, if you need to use BULK COLLECT you are probably dealing with more data than is appropriate for an associative array.

**Edit**

A cheap-ish performance test of the two approaches:

```
SQL> declare
  2      type n_array is table of varchar2(30)
  3           index by binary_integer;
  4      emp_names n_array;
  5      s_time pls_integer;
  6      e_time pls_integer;
  7  begin
  8      s_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
  9      select ename
 10      bulk collect into emp_names
 11      from big_emp
 12      where rownum <= 500;
 13      dbms_output.put_line('bulk collect elapsed time = '
 14                              ||to_char(dbms_utility.get_time - s_time));
 15      s_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
 16      for r in ( select ename, empno from big_emp
 17                 where rownum <= 500 )
 18      loop
 19          emp_names(r.empno) := r.ename;
 20      end loop;
 21      dbms_output.put_line('sparse array elapsed time = '
 22                              ||to_char(dbms_utility.get_time - s_time));
 23  end;
 24  /

bulk collect elapsed time = 0
sparse array elapsed time = 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Wall-clock performance tests are notoriously ropey.  But for a few hundred records, any difference is unlikely to be worth worrying about, certainly in the context of the sort of place where we might want to use an assoociative array.

**Edit 2**

@Dan said:

> t seems to me that wanting to query a
>   decent sized number of rows into a
>   data structure that can be used for
>   constant-time lookup ought to be a
>   pretty common need

It really depends on your definition of "a decent sized number".  Are there really that many cases where we would want to populate *an associative array* with thousands of rows, with a string index?  When we get to those sorts of numbers a normal database table might be just as useful, especially on [11g Enterprise Edition with resultset caching](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/memory.htm#PFGRF10121).

Comment: How many is that? My understanding was that even for relatively small numbers of rows (say, a few hundred) the overhead of the SQL to PL/SQL context switch was enough to merit using BULK COLLECT. Does your first example (for loop on a cursor) not have that issue?

Comment: As FEUERSTEIN himself advises, never use cursor FOR loops unless you're dealing with small numbers of rows (hundreds). (Or you simply don't give a damn about performance)

Comment: Hm. Well, then, what's the right answer here? It seems to me that wanting to query a decent sized number of rows into a data structure that can be used for constant-time lookup ought to be a pretty common need.