# PL/SQL program that uses a Loop for Payment Schedule with COLLECTION

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am learning about LOOPS, Records, and Collections.   I have a program that I'm working on for a Payment Schedule for a Donor Pledge Amount of $1500.  The PL/SQL program runs a payment schedule of 24 months, retrieves the balance from a donation Table called dd_pledge for donor with ID '111', shows the payments amount for  each payment, and shows the 24 payments with the BALANCE after each payment down to a ZERO balance.  I've included the Table info below, however, I'm only inserting one value from that table into my collection, and then performing calculations on it.  This is the desired result for the payments:

anonymous block completed

---

Pay #: 1 Due: 10/01/2012 Amt: $62.50 Bal: $1,437.50

---

Pay #: 2 Due: 11/01/2012 Amt: $62.50 Bal: $1,375.00

---

... Pay #: 23 Due: 08/01/2014 Amt: $62.50 Bal: $62.50

---

Pay #: 24 Due: 09/01/2014 Amt: $62.50 Bal: $.00

The startdate for the program is'01-OCT-2012' and the payment amount is 62.50 for 24 payments.

I'm using a RECORD and LOOP for this program but it's not working.

I still could use some GUIDANCE on PAYMENT BALANCE iteration in the LOOP and the MONTH only adding 1 month for NOV and using that throughout. That is where I need to add the collection part to my coding and call those values for the LOOP.

Here is my updated coding that is a little simpler, but not sure about the BALANCE calculation entry into the LOOP, and also the payment date from 01-Oct-12 just goes to 01-NOV and uses that as the date.  I'm still learning about COLLECTIONS.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
payment_num                      NUMBER(2) := 0;
d_loop_count                     NUMBER(2) := 24;
due_date                         DATE;
payment_amt                      NUMBER(8, 2) := 62.50;
donation_balance                 NUMBER(8,2); 
pledgeamt                        NUMBER(8,2) := 1500;
---This pledgeamt is not correct, involved in Collection called value from TABLE
start_date                       DATE :=  '01-OCT-2012'; 

BEGIN
 /*
 SELECT pledgeamt  INTO donation_balance
    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idpledge = '111';  --111 has a pledge amount of $1500
*/
FOR i IN 1..d_loop_count
LOOP
payment_num :=payment_num + 1;
due_date := add_months(start_date, 1);
donation_balance := (pledgeamt - payment_amt);

dbms_output.put_line
(
'Pay #: ' || payment_num 
|| ' ' || 'Due: ' || due_date
|| ' ' ||  'Amt: ' || payment_amt
|| ' ' || 'Bal: '|| donation_balance
);

END LOOP;

END;
/
```

This is what the spool gives me.  It's coming along but need a little more help on the LOOP iterations and the calculations for Donation Payment Balance and the MONTH countdown there for the payment sequences.

```
    anonymous block completed
Pay #: 1 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 2 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 3 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 4 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
...Pay #: 20 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 21 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 22 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 23 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
Pay #: 24 Due: 01-NOV-12 Amt: 62.5 Bal: 1437.5
```

Here is the Table info I will be using to input that Balance from the Donation Table into the LOOP.

TABLE dd_pledge info is

```
IDPLEDGE    NUMBER(5,0) No      1   
IDDONOR NUMBER(4,0) Yes     2   
PLEDGEDATE  DATE    Yes     3   
PLEDGEAMT   NUMBER(8,2) Yes     4   
IDPROJ  NUMBER(5,0) Yes     5   
IDSTATUS    NUMBER(2,0) Yes     6   
WRITEOFF    NUMBER(8,2) Yes     7   
PAYMONTHS   NUMBER(3,0) Yes     8   
CAMPAIGN    NUMBER(4,0) Yes     9   
FIRSTPLEDGE CHAR(1 BYTE)    Yes     10

111 ROW equals:

IDPLEDGE   IDDONOR         PLEDGEDATE         PLEDGEAMT
111        306         01-MAR-13          1500                                      

 etc...
 504       20   0   756   Y
```

Here is the section on Collections, Records, which is what I'm working on for others to learn more about PL/SQL COLLECTIONS. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDBHJEI

Comment: "showing" the payments over time can be done via SQL and joins.  But I'm sure someone will beat me to the punch soon ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
payment_num                       NUMBER(2) := 0;
d_loop_count                      NUMBER(2) := 24;
payment_amt                       NUMBER(8, 2);
donation_balance                  NUMBER(8,2);
v_pledgeamt                       NUMBER(8,2);
start_date                        DATE :=  '01-OCT-2012';
due_date                          DATE;
v_due_date                        VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN

 SELECT pledgeamt  INTO v_pledgeamt    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idpledge = &idpledge;

payment_amt := v_pledgeamt / d_loop_count;
due_date := start_date;
donation_balance := (v_pledgeamt - payment_amt);

FOR i IN 1..d_loop_count
LOOP
payment_num :=payment_num + 1;
v_due_date := TO_CHAR(due_date,'mm/dd/yyyy');
due_date := add_months(due_date, 1);
dbms_output.put_line
(
'Pay #: ' || payment_num
|| ' ' || 'Due: ' || v_due_date
|| ' ' ||  'Amt: ' || payment_amt
|| ' ' || 'Bal: '|| to_char(donation_balance, '$9999.99')
);

donation_balance := (donation_balance - payment_amt);

END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on existing Oracle emp table - sorry no time to dig into your code and you did not post any sample data. Always create tables and data when posting questions. Besides, I agree with tbone, unless you are learning PL/SQL use SQL whenever possible. Copy/paste to see results. Do not use SELECT... INTO inside a loop as in your code.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM scott.emp;
  TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF scott.emp%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  emp_tab  EmpTabTyp;
  i        BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
     i := i + 1;
     FETCH c1 INTO emp_tab(i);
     EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    --dbms_output.put_line(emp_tab(i).empno);
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE c1;
END;
/

DECLARE
  TYPE EmpTabTyp IS TABLE OF scott.emp%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  emp_tab      EmpTabTyp;
  i            BINARY_INTEGER := 0;
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM scott.emp;
BEGIN
-- Method 1 - the BULK COLLECT is faster --
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO emp_tab FROM scott.emp;

  dbms_output.put_line('BULK example:'||chr(13));

  -- Display values in emp_tab --
  --FOR i IN emp_tab.first .. emp_tab.last LOOP  -- or use COUNT method as below --
  FOR i IN 1 .. emp_tab.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||emp_tab(i).empno||' '||emp_tab(i).ename);
 END LOOP;

 dbms_output.put_line(chr(13)||'END BULK example'||chr(13));

 -- Method 2 - Loop --
 FOR e_rec IN c1 LOOP
   i:= i+1;
    emp_tab(i).empno:= e_rec.empno;
    dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||emp_tab(i).empno);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: BULK collect is faster than? It has been a while for oracle to use bulk collect under the hood with explicit cursors. ;)

Comment: @Art  [Bulk Collect into Associative Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715736/pl-sql-bulk-collect-into-associative-array-with-sparse-key)

Comment: @MeachamRob - still not sure what do you mean, sorry. Do you see error in my code? Where?

Comment: @Art I don't know, what did *you* mean with your comment: _Method 1 - the BULK COLLECT is faster_ ?

Comment: @Plouf - It is irrelevant and not worth arguing about. Oracle says BULK COLLECT is faster then row by row processing. And at the same time they say they optimized the FOR loop and it is basically as fast as BC. You may agree or not - does not matter. This is what Oracle writes in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the correct dates and amount paid/months:

```
    DECLARE
payment_num                       NUMBER(2) := 0;
d_loop_count                      NUMBER(2) := 24; --PAYMONTHS
payment_amt                       NUMBER(8, 2);
donation_balance                  NUMBER(8,2);
v_pledgeamt                       NUMBER(8,2);
start_date                        DATE :=  '01-OCT-2012';
due_date                          DATE;
v_due_date                        VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN

 SELECT pledgeamt, PAYMONTHS, PLEDGEDATE INTO v_pledgeamt, d_loop_count, start_date    FROM dd_pledge
    WHERE idpledge = &idpledge;


--d_loop_count := PAYMONTHS;
--start_date := PLEDGEDATE;

payment_amt := v_pledgeamt / d_loop_count;
due_date := start_date;
donation_balance := (v_pledgeamt - payment_amt);

FOR i IN 1..d_loop_count
LOOP
payment_num :=payment_num + 1;
v_due_date := TO_CHAR(due_date,'mm/dd/yyyy');
due_date := add_months(due_date, 1);
dbms_output.put_line
(
'Pay #: ' || payment_num
|| ' ' || 'Due: ' || v_due_date
|| ' ' ||  'Amt: ' || payment_amt
|| ' ' || 'Bal: '|| to_char(donation_balance, '$9999.99')
);

donation_balance := (donation_balance - payment_amt);

END LOOP;

END;
```